# How to access Activity UI from my class?

Tags: android, android-context

I have an activity which creates an object instance of my class:

```
file MyActivity.java:
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
    ...
    Points myPoints new Points();
    ...
}
--------------------------------------------------------------

file Points.java:
private class Points {
    ...
    HOW TO USE myView HERE ???
    ...
}
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I use the UI objects in my class (which does not extend an 
Activity)? Should I pass some context to my Points class? How do I do, exactly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

see you post, i've edited it , to fix the problem

hope it helps :=)

here is the Edit :

```
file MyActivity.java:
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView myView ;
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
            Points myPoints = new Points(this);
            myPoints.displayMsg("Hello World !!!");
    }  
    }

--------------------------------------------------------------

file Points.java:
private class Points {
    protected MyActivity context;
    //add a constructor with the Context of your activity
    public Points(MyActivity _context){
        context = _context;
    }

    public void displayMsg( final String msg){
        context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.myView.setText(msg);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, which problem did you fix?

Comment: @Marcos : as i understand , you want to access to your activity from your class Points, which means , you want to modify and update your TextViews or your ImageViews etc , 
 i 've edited your Code ,but  Admins doesn't accept the edit, i will post it now in my Answer , wait a second :)

Comment: Why would you edit it and not post an answer? wtf XD

Fantastic answer though, thank you.

Comment: @Sipty : I've edited his question for him to understand , because i didn't want to copy paste all the code in the answer, and Then i've added the edited part in my answer for others :D

Comment: I'm trying to apply this to the app I created as part of following the Firebase "Getting Started" guide.  I can receive messages and I see them in the Log.  For the Listener when the app is backgrounded I even see them in the Notifications.  But now I'd like to update a textView with the received message.  Problem is the Firebase Message Service is apparently instantiated by magic, I don't have an opportunity to pass it my MainActivity context?

Answer (score 4):

1. Your `Points` can't be a private class without being an inner class. So your code doesn't even compile...
2. Pass the view as parameter to the constructor of your `Points` class:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {
       TextView myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
       Points myPoints new Points(myView);

       private class Points {
           public Points(TextView view) {
               // todo
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should do everything and pass back the value to the activity to handle UI instead of doing any UI related stuff in the point stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the main Activity's context (using `Points(getApplicationContext());`) to the class as a constructor parameter.  You could also pass the specific UI elements you want to manipulate.

A better way to do it, however, may be to have `Points` not know about the Activity.  Have your Activity call `Points` methods and take the necessary actions based on the method output.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the view to your class.

```
Points myPoints = new Points(myView);

private class Points
{
  private TextView mTextView;

  Points(TextView textView)
  {
     this.mTextView = textView;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was in same trouble..
i found the simple way..

1. make a static variable and function ...
2. call from other class..

## TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

   static EditText edit_text1;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {   
       .....

       edit_text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);  

       .....
   }

   public static void setMSG(String str)
   {
       edit_text1.setText(str);
   }
}
```

---

## Test2.java

```
TestActivity.setMSG("this is text");
```

Comment: dnt make static contexts

Answer (score 0):

Could work using an interface

**file MyActivity.java:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Points.MyListener {

    TextView myView;
    ... onCreate(...){
        myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
        Points myPoints  = new Points();

        //pass in MyActivity's instance of the listener
        myPoints.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTextView(String message){
        myView.setMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**file Points.java:**

```
public class Points {

    public Points(){

    }

    public interface MyListener{
        void updateTextView(String message);
    }
    MyListener myListener;

    public void addListener(MyListener listener){
        myListener = listener;
    }

    public void updatePoints(){
        //do some operations in calculatePoints()
        String points = calculatePoints();
        //update views using MyActivity's implementation of updateTextView()
        myListener.updateTextView(points);
    }

}
```

Doing it this way, `events` can be fired / messages sent, for lack of better terms, from the external class to update the Activity UI. This might be overkill if all sb need is to call a method in the Points class that returns something

Answer (score 0):

Since it can be quite frustrating to always make sure the call runs on a UI thread from the caller, and you may have multiple calls from different places from your application, making a duplicite code for the **running on UI thread**, I propose a recursion approach, where the process is ran on UI thread from the method itself.

```
void setUiSynchronizing(boolean state)
        {
            if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() != Thread.currentThread())
            {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    setUiSynchronizing(state);
                });
                return;
            }
    
            ProgressBar pb = findViewById(R.id.sync_loading);
            if(state)
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

In the example above you see the target method, which manipulates the UI. We can then just call it from other class, simply as:

```
mainActivity.setUiSynchronizing(state);
```