# How to change position of point as per screen resolution?

Tags: android

Suppose I put some points as (x1,y1) = (133,123), (x2,y2) = (149,136), (x3,y3) = (182,136) and so on which makes a shape something like this:
[image]
[image]

Now I want to change the position of these points as per the screen resolution such that the shape gets resized and gets centered and also such that the shape doesn't get damaged. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the scale factor from the `DisplayMetrics` as shown in the [Android - Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels) documentation:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Multiply all you x and y coordinates with `scale` and your points are screen density independent.

To fit the image on the screen (or `View` probably), you can grab the [width](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) and [height](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29) of your View. Check the width and height of your image and calculate the maximum scale factor.

Combine (multiply) both scale factors and your image should fit your View.

Answer (score 1):

you can use onMeasure method to get measure then you can start painting with that position. I dont know below code is working truly, maybe it need to be optimized.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();

        // Find the center
        px = width / 2;
        py = height / 2;

        canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        // TODO remove if you dont want points to be drawn
        for (Point point : mPoints) {
            canvas.drawPoint(point.x + px, point.y + py, mPaint);
        }
    }




@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredHeight = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        int measuredWidth = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight, measuredWidth);
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        // Default size if no limits are specified.
        int result = 500;

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // Calculate the ideal size of your
            // control within this maximum size.
            // If your control fills the available
            // space return the outer bound.
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // If your control can fit within these bounds return that value.
            result = specSize;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        // Default size if no limits are specified.
        int result = 500;

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // Calculate the ideal size of your control
            // within this maximum size.
            // If your control fills the available space
            // return the outer bound.
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // If your control can fit within these bounds return that value.
            result = specSize;
        }

        return result;
    }
```