# Toogle ProgressBar from different AsyncTask Class return NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I want to do Asychronous task on android, I made that on different class rather inside the activity. My problem is when I want to set ProgressBar visibility from INVISIBLE to GONE it return NullPointerException. I don't understand why, this is my code so far.

```
package com.ursabyte.boxi;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class SyncPercobaan extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String> {

    AktifitasUtama ut;
    ManajemenFile mf;
    ProgressBar loading;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) ut.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        loading.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) ut.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        loading.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        ut.browseToRoot();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String dir_name = (String) params[0];
        ut = (AktifitasUtama) params[1];
        ManajemenFile mf = new ManajemenFile(ut);
        mf.retrieve_user_dir();
        return dir_name;
    }
}
```

AktifitasUtama is my Main Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is context.runOnUiThread. In my case ut.runOnUiThread. And here is the code :

```
public class SyncPercobaan extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String> {

    AktifitasUtama ut;
    ManajemenFile mf;
    ManajemenKoneksi mk;
    SessionManager session;
    DatabaseHandler dh;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        final String res = response; 
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        session = new SessionManager(ut);
        ut.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ut.toogle_indicator(false);
                ut.display_toast(res);
            }
        });
        ut.browseToRoot();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String dir_name = (String) params[0];
        ut = (AktifitasUtama) params[1];
        session = new SessionManager(ut);
        mk = new ManajemenKoneksi(ut);
        if(mk.is_connected()){
            ut.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ut.display_toast("Starting syncing...");
                    ut.toogle_indicator(true);
                }
            });     
            ManajemenFile mf = new ManajemenFile(ut);
            String result = mf.retrieve_user_dir(dir_name);
            if(result.equals("true")){
                return "Syncing completed...";
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            return "Internet connection unavailable";
        }
    }

}

class Task extends TimerTask {
    AktifitasUtama au;
    String dir_name;
    Task(AktifitasUtama ut, String dir_name){
        au=ut;
        this.dir_name=dir_name;
    }

    public void run() {
        ManajemenFile mf = new ManajemenFile(au);
        mf.retrieve_user_dir(dir_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here

```
public class SyncPercobaan extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String> {

    AktifitasUtama ut;  //<<--here
```

this not right way to get access Ui elements from Activity to on Activity class as in your case in `AsyncTask`

for accessing UI elements from non Activity class create an constructor of non Activity as:

```
public class SyncPercobaan extends AsyncTask<Object, Boolean, String> {
Context context;
    SyncPercobaan(Context context){
      this.context=context;
    }
  //your code here
```

now use `context` for accessing all UI elements from `AktifitasUtama`

Comment: how do I get the ProgressBar, at first I'm using ut, but I don't know this time :s

Comment: @tegaralaga : see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030982/android-how-to-access-activity-ui-from-my-class) for accessing Ui from non Activity class